# Handling errors - should I use exceptions or events in an "event driven" application?

Tags: c#, oop

I am developing a small application that works like a script. I'll give it some urls and it will extract some useful info from them. As it is downloading the files and parsing the information, it's also raising events so that there's a listener, it will be able to read everything it wants.

The system is basically as follows:

```
class UrlInfoExtractor {
    ...

    public void Run() {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

As always, there's the risk of errors (i.e., there's no internet at the moment). At first I thought it would be good idea to have the `Run()` method throw some exceptions of my own (`BadLoginException`, `BadUrlException`, etc). But as there are already so many defined events, I came to think maybe it would be better to also have the errors pop up as events (I'm assuming that whatever error I get, I'll just stop the process). The whole approach to the system would be more.. consistent. On the other hand, it would allow errors to go unnoticed if the developers didn't care to listen to the error events.

Am I better using exceptions or raising events, in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is truly an error, I would raise an exception.  The down side with using events is that if the caller does not add a handler for an exception event, they will not be notified there was an error and may assume that everything worked correctly.

If you are against raising exceptions, you could always return a status instead of your function being a void.  That may allow you to avoid using exceptions for control flow, but you still have the ability to return information to the caller about the status of the call.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to stop your script or application anyway,  I would suggest bubbling the exception up. You can catch and re-throw it wherever you need to clean up or save state. 'hiding'  all your exceptions behind events is rarely a good idea.

If you're expecting exceptions often, john's suggestion on returning values instead of void will make for a cleaner in implementation if you intend to keep your script running.

As a sidenote,  consistent doesn't necessarily equate to 'good'. Use language features for their purpose as far as possible.